# Apache Beam - Python - Streaming to BigQuery writes no data to the table

Tags: python, google-bigquery, apache-beam

## Apache Beam - Python - Streaming to BigQuery writes no data to the table

I have designed a simple Apache Beam Pipeline using the Python SDK, while I know that the streaming capabilities of the Python SDK are still being developed I have stumbled upon a roadblock I cannot seem to circumvent: everything in the Pipeline works fine, until the point where I try to stream into a BigQuery table. I get no error, exception or warning, the data simply does not appear on BigQuery.

- I tried both with 2.1.0 and 2.2.0 and it yields the same results.
- The PubSub topic where I am fetching the data from simply contains tweets like "I love Apache Beam #apachebeam #dataflow #beam #datascience".

This is the Pipeline:

```
import datetime
import logging

import apache_beam as beam
import apache_beam.transforms.window as window

from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import StandardOptions

# Configuration
# I set all the constant before creating the Pipeline Options
options = PipelineOptions()
options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True
options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = 'DirectRunner'
# options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
# options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = 'DataflowRunner'
google_cloud_options = options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
google_cloud_options.project = PROJECT_ID


# DoFn
class ExtractHashtagsDoFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        """
        Takes a tweet as input, search and return its content 
        and hashtag as a dictionary.
        """
        hastags = [w for w in element.split() if w.startswith('#')]
        result = {'tweet': element, 'hashtags': hastags}
        logging.info('{}'.format(result))
        yield result


class SentimentAnalysisDoFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        from google.cloud import language
        from google.gax.errors import RetryError

        client = language.LanguageServiceClient()
        document = language.types.Document(
            content=element['tweet'].encode('utf-8'),
            type='PLAIN_TEXT')

        try:
            response = client.analyze_sentiment(
                document=document,
                encoding_type='UTF8')
            sentiment = response.document_sentiment
            element['sentiment_score'] = sentiment.score
            element['sentiment_magnitude'] = sentiment.magnitude
            element['analyzed'] = 1

        except RetryError:
            element['sentiment_score'] = None
            element['sentiment_magnitude'] = None
            element['analyzed'] = 0

#         logging.info('{}'.format(element))
        yield element


# Define Composite Transforms
class TextAnalysisTransform(beam.PTransform):
    def expand(self, pcoll):
        return(
            pcoll
            | 'Decode' >> beam.Map(lambda string: string.decode('utf8', 'ignore'))
            | 'ExtractHashtags' >> beam.ParDo(ExtractHashtagsDoFn())
            | 'SentimentAnalysis' >> beam.ParDo(SentimentAnalysisDoFn())
        )


class WindowingForOutputTransform(beam.PTransform):
    def expand(self, pcoll):
        import json
        return(
            pcoll
            | 'Pack' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x, 1))
            | 'Windowing' >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(5, 0))
            | 'GroupByKey' >> beam.GroupByKey()
            | 'Unpack' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x[0])
        )


class SaveToBigQueryTransform(beam.PTransform):
    def expand(self, pcoll):
        # Define the Schema.
        from apache_beam.io.gcp.internal.clients import bigquery

        table_schema = bigquery.TableSchema()

        # Fields that use standard types.
        alpha_schema = bigquery.TableFieldSchema()
        alpha_schema.name = 'tweet'
        alpha_schema.type = 'string'
        alpha_schema.mode = 'nullable'
        table_schema.fields.append(alpha_schema)

        beta_schema = bigquery.TableFieldSchema()
        beta_schema.name = 'sentiment_score'
        beta_schema.type = 'float'
        beta_schema.mode = 'nullable'
        table_schema.fields.append(beta_schema)

        gamma_schema = bigquery.TableFieldSchema()
        gamma_schema.name = 'sentiment_magnitude'
        gamma_schema.type = 'float'
        gamma_schema.mode = 'nullable'
        table_schema.fields.append(gamma_schema)

        delta_schema = bigquery.TableFieldSchema()
        delta_schema.name = 'analyzed'
        delta_schema.type = 'integer'
        delta_schema.mode = 'required'
        table_schema.fields.append(delta_schema)

        # A repeated field.
        omega_schema = bigquery.TableFieldSchema()
        omega_schema.name = 'hashtags'
        omega_schema.type = 'string'
        omega_schema.mode = 'repeated'
        table_schema.fields.append(omega_schema)

        # Saving the output to BigQuery.
        return (
            pcoll
            | 'PrepareForOutput' >> WindowingForOutputTransform()
            | 'WriteToBigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                table='twitter_analysis',
                dataset=DATASET_ID,
                project=PROJECT_ID,
                schema=table_schema,  # Pass the defined table_schema
                create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND))


def run(argv=None):
    """
    Define and run the pipeline.
    """
    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        plumbing = (
            p
            | 'LoadTestData' >> beam.io.ReadStringsFromPubSub(subscription=FULL_SUBSCRIPTION)
            | 'TextAnalysis' >> TextAnalysisTransform()
            | 'StreamToBigQuery' >> SaveToBigQueryTransform()
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

> **Output:**
>   /home/ubik/Documents/github/twitter-streaming/beam/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/typecoders.py:135:
>   UserWarning: Using fallback coder for typehint: Any.
>             warnings.warn('Using fallback coder for typehint: %r.' % typehint)
>           INFO:root:Running pipeline with DirectRunner.

**EDIT:** I tried to run the pipeline again on September 4, everything worked fine. Probably the BigQuery poltergeist stopped haunting me.

Comment: You process data before streaming it to BigQuery. Have you checked if actual data is available for streaming?

A valuable series of data streaming to BigQuery in Python can be found on the "Apache Beam WordCount Example" documentation page. [1]

[1] https://beam.apache.org/get-started/wordcount-example/

Comment: Do you see the elements logged in the ExtractHashTagDoFn as based on the output you don't seem to be seeing anything there itself so my guess is something is wrong in reading the source?

Comment: I do not really know what happened, but the code now runs fine. Could it be related to last week BigQuery's incident? I would consider the issue solved.